# Figure out lambda name from AWS API-Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

There is a Jenkins job which deploys `AWS-lambda`, and by default, APIs get created at `API-Gateway`. Since AWS provides facility to modify lambda on AWS itself, I want to make some changes in the functionality and test it. I have access to the `API-Gateway`, Is there a way I can know the name of lambda deployed behind one of the APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log into API gateway, then select an API (by clicking on its title), click `Resources` on the left, expand the tree out under Resources to view the methods and then select the method - here you can view the endpoint.

If you are using stages (ie prod, test etc) and are using environment variables, you will need to select the API, then click `Stages` on the left and look under the relevent stage and method to see the endpoint

Edit/Add:
OK, now I understand what you need :) Under resources, look at the methods. Look at the `Integration Request` (which is presumably of type Lambda?). Click on integration request. It has a parameter under there called `Lambda Function` - it will either be defined here or otherwise refer you to your stage variables. If it refers to your stage variables - look at `Stages` on the left, click on the stage environment (NOT the methods) and look at the tab `Stage Variables`. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I know how to see the endpoint, but, how do I see the lambda associated with this particular end-point.